# iPad - Adding 1000 mp3 files

Tags: ipad, resources

I have 20mb of mp3 files I want to add into my app for the iPad... I'm about to just add them all into an mp3 directory in my resources directory, anyone have any better ideas? This isn't too big for an app is it?

zip/unzip at load time?? Is it possible to leave them in a zip and just pull them out when I want to play them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

20MB is hardly anything - MYST is nearly 1GB, for example. Or did you mean 20GB (which could make sense for 1000 song-length MP3s)?

Compressing MP3s would probably not save space - they're already compressed.

Comment: Didn't know if iPad app store had a limit on app file sizes? I remember iphone has 25mb or something. I may be thinking of the android market..